# How to get the error count value of file upload

Tags: php, file

Here i have one array, in that array i want to take only error,how can take the value of error, I am new PHP developer i tried but i am not getting the answer i tried like this echo $_FILES['file']['error'],but is not printing the output

> print_r($_FILES)

```
Array
(
[file] => Array
    (
        [name] => Array
            (
                [0] => 1.png
            )

        [type] => Array
            (
                [0] => image/png
            )

        [tmp_name] => Array
            (
                [0] => C:\xampp5.6\tmp\php96F6.tmp
            )

        [error] => Array
            (
                [0] => 0
            )

        [size] => Array
            (
                [0] => 166275
            )

    )

   )
```

Comment: try print_r($_FILES['file'])

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php  `[error] => Array
            (
                [0] => 0
            )` your upload didn't fail (yet). As per the manual *"Value: 0; There is no error, the file uploaded with success."*

Comment: This is mere php 101. You have the output dump array.besides the upload went through successfully. To fully comprehend how arrays work and how to iterate, you need to go back to the roots of php tutorials

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to get the error value then this code will help you.

```
$error = $_FILES['file']['error'][0];
```

Comment: Maybe add more explanation as OP is a newbie

Answer (score 1):

Error 0 means the upload was successful.

The codes are (from http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php):

> UPLOAD_ERR_OK Value: 0; There is no error, the file uploaded with
>   success.
>
> UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE Value: 1; The uploaded file exceeds the
>   upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini.
>
> UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE Value: 2; The uploaded file exceeds the
>   MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in the HTML form.
>
> UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL Value: 3; The uploaded file was only partially
>   uploaded.
>
> UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE Value: 4; No file was uploaded.
>
> UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR Value: 6; Missing a temporary folder. Introduced
>   in PHP 5.0.3.
>
> UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE Value: 7; Failed to write file to disk.
>   Introduced in PHP 5.1.0.
>
> UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION Value: 8; A PHP extension stopped the file
>   upload. PHP does not provide a way to ascertain which extension caused
>   the file upload to stop; examining the list of loaded extensions with
>   phpinfo() may help. Introduced in PHP 5.2.0.

In your case you get the error from `$_FILES['file']['error'][0]` and then find that `0` means `UPLOAD_ERR_OK` — there is no error.

If you *don't* check for the error, then you will find that http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php won't work.